# How can I move a MS Word "toolbox" when the grab area is behind the OS X menu bar?

Tags: applications, ms-office, desktop, menu-bar

MS Word has positioned what they call a "toolbox" so that the area you click on to drag it is hidden behind OS X's menu bar, as shown in the screen capture below...

[image]

There is no place on the palette (or "toolbox") where I can click on it to move it.

I tried hiding and showing it again via **View > Toolbox,** but it always reappears in the same inaccessible location.

I tried restarting the machine.

How can I release it from captivity?

Comment: Try changing the screen resolution to something lower - this will often force palettes to reposition. If it works, move it to an accessible spot and switch back to the higher resolution and it should stay in the same relative spot.

Comment: @douggro, you should post it as an answer so Agvorth can mark it as solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with problems like this by changing the display resolution to a lower value. This will often force floating palettes to reposition themselves. If the palette moves, reposition it to an accessible spot and switch back to the original screen resolution; you can now position the palette where you wish.

This also works for modal dialogs or pop-up windows where the controls are positioned off-screen, though it may require jumping to a higher resolution (if available) to have access to the window or menu controls.